# Magento Community 1.9.1 RWD theme: Home page "add to cart" formatting not correct on Iphone or android

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, mobile

When I test the site for responsiveness and formatting on a pc, The smallest screen size settings show proper formatting for my products under the "New Products" widget on my home page. But when I use an iPhone or Android device, the formatting under each product image isn't correct. Any Suggestions?

Comment: http://kaleidoscopiacoloringbooks.com/Store/

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by incorrect formatting?